# How to generate a GET request Swagger API Doc in Laravel 5.8 API?

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I'm using [L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnline/L5-Swagger) framework to generate an API Doc for my Laravel 5.8 project.
Here is the code I have created so far:

```
 /**
 * @OA\GET(
 *     path="/api/articles",
 *     tags={"articles"},
 *     summary="Returns articles with limit and offset",
 *     description="Description by Chanaka",
 *     operationId="sampleFunctionWithDoc",
 * )
 * @OA\Parameter(
 *    description="limit",
 *    in="path",
 *    name="limit",
 *    required=true,
 *    example="1",
 * )
 * @OA\Response(
 *    response="default",
 *    description="successful operation"
 * )
 * 
 */
public function showAllArticles($limit, $offset)
{
    return response()->json(Article::skip($offset)->take($limit)->get());
}
```

This is an endpoint with limit and offset. I added limit as a parameter here just to check. But it is not generating. Only the endpoint with path is available in the Swagger UI.

[image]

Please tell me what is the issue with my syntax.
Is there another way to implement this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe annotations should be like this:

```
/**
 * @OA\GET(
 *     path="/api/articles",
 *     tags={"articles"},
 *     summary="Returns articles with limit and offset",
 *     description="Description by Chanaka",
 *     operationId="sampleFunctionWithDoc",
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *       description="limit",
 *       in="path",
 *       name="limit",
 *       required=true,
 *       example="1",
 *    ),
 *    @OA\Response(
 *       response="default",
 *       description="successful operation"
 *    )
 *  )
 * 
 */
```

So basically your parameters and response definitions should be another line in the root of the GET path "/api/articles" declaration.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and I will check this now.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked. Can you please refer me a getting started guide with the new Swagger @OA method. Everything I got has old Swagger methods.

Comment: Glad it worked. You could check this link: https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/Getting-started.html